# Rails API - Voting app, associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-api

So, I am developing a **small** voting app. I am using **Rails**, but as **JSON API-only**. 
I want to create voters table for every voting - so that every voting has the same voters (this is app for local community in which voters will remain mostly 'static'), but it would be nice to have an 'presence list' for every voting.

I have created controllers - **scores** and **voters**. Now:

How would you do it to include always **the same** list of voters, but with boolean presence? I have added voter_presence: boolean, as well added something like that to routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :scores do
    resources :voters
  end
end
```

And it should do the trick with associations - but I still have a  "**every score the same list**" problem.

Comment: is there a model for the `voting`?

Comment: no, I have added just length of the markers to the `scores` (markers which are votes)

Comment: so when a new issue is being voted on a new score is added to the table?

Comment: Yes - the root page is 'creating voting' - then we can either start voting (with full 'presence') or edit presence, save and back to the root where we can begin voting. The scores 'votes' are null at the beggning.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a [HABTM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) table between scores, and voters.

Such that each score would have only the voters that are present.

Then you would add a abstract attribute like `excluded_voter_ids` and an after create call back like `add_voters` to the scores model, 

the `add_voters`, would iterate over the voters and add them to the HABTM association unless they are in the `excluded_voter_ids`

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that, although I am looking for simpler solution similar to the association one I have written about (in `routes.rb`). Maybe just route to 'voters table' which would be a 'setter' for the rest of the voter tables. But if I won't find better solution I'll use HABTM one.

Comment: I'd like to ask: _why_? When you write that you want to create a voters table for every voting. What are you trying to accomplish? This seems to violate [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) quite a bit... Judging from your use case, a simple `Voter HABTM Scores` model would suffice. When someone votes for a subject, add them to the relation. Your "every score the same list-problem" seems like a simple `voters left outer join scores` (to use SQL DB lingo).

Comment: @MichaelGorman I see this is a very good solution. Could you expand a little on it? Where would you add an `excluded_voter_ids`? To the scores or voters? Should it be like nested list? I am aware that it may seem pretty obvious, but I am not sure how it should look at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :voters
  attr_accessor :excluded_voter_ids
  after_create :add_voters

  ... other code ...

  def add_voters
    Voter.where().not(id: excluded_voter_ids).find_each do |voter|
      self.voters << voter
    end
  end
end
```

You will also need to follow the instructions [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) for setting up the HABTM association